# PHP list array names and values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
<?php
// My PHP version is 5.3.5
$arr = array("num"=>6,"book"=>"Polyanna","name"=>"Fred","age"=>8)
?>
```

How do I list the category's in the array and their values, to result something like this:

num: 6

book: Polyanna

name: Fred

age: 8

Comment: Really, this is basic php that is not worth anyone's time to answer. Even the most horrible of php tutorials can show you how to do this. If this is your first day using php then take some time to read up on it and experiment yourself. I am surprised that you can even ask this with the amount of time you have spent on this site (judging by your reputation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can't write arrays like that in PHP. You need to use this notation:

```
<?php
$arr = array('num' => 6, 'book' => 'Polyanna', 'name' => 'Fred', 'age' => 8);
?>
```

To list as you described, a `foreach` loop will suffice:

```
<?php
$final_str = "";
foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    $final_str .= $key . ": " . $value . "\n";
}
?>
```

Or, if you just need to `echo` the data:

```
<?php
foreach ( $arr as $key => $value ) {
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: This answer looks more like a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need `=>` instead of `=` while declaring array

```
$arr = array("num"=>6,"book"=>"Polyanna","name"=>"Fred","age"=>8)
```

and iterate through foreach loop to retrieve values

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key. ":". $value;
}
```